# What would be the best way to combine several denoised images and achieve superior denoising results?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, preprocessing, image

I have generated denoised images using several models and would like to create an ensemble of these individual images to achieve superior denoising results. What would be the best way to combine (averaging, max voting, weighted averaging, etc.) these denoised images to achieve a superior denoised image?

Comment: after a point not much better can be achieved else we would have a holy grail. However some majority voting scheme migjht help